# AngularJS current route path?

Tags: angularjs

this may sound strange, but I need to check for current route path in my controller. I wasnt able to find the answer.

I have 3 routes: the default "/", "Report" and "Preview".

How can I check the route in the controller?

```
    constructor(
        private dataService: DataService,
        private $scope: ng.IScope,
        private $location: ng.ILocationService,
        private $route, // what type should it be (for typescript)?
        private $routeParams: IRouteParams,
        private $log: ng.ILogService) {

        var xxx = $route.current; // doesnt work, undefined always
    }
```

Comment: So is this Angular or Angular 2.x?  This is ***very important.***

Comment: The type your are looking for `$route` is `private $route: IRouteService`, it has an optional property `current`. [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-route/index.d.ts#L29)

Comment: In addition to @AlexanderStaroselsky, you need to install the angular-route typings so that the `IRouteService` interface is available through `ng.route.IRouteService`. `$routeParams` is actually available through `ng.route.IRouteParamsService`.

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky, yes, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The `$location` service has two methods you can use `$location.path()` and `$location.url()`

The AngularJS documentation should be clear enough:

- [$location.path()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) - Returns the curent path of the current route
- [$location.url()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#url) - Returns the full url